# Problemas desplegar informacion en TableView en javafx

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, scenebuilder

Estoy empezando con JavaFX y scene builder, tengo que diseñar un programa para la universidad mi programa debe tener un apartado administrador Y para ello tengo un controlador que permite hacer el CRUD de los empleados de un hostpital, al momento de iniciar la aplicación creo por defecto unos empleados que se agregan a un arrayList sin problema, ya revisé e incluso permite loguearse a la aplicacion, mi problema esta en que cuando trato de mostrar la información en una tabla, esta aparece vacía, ya hice un debug y lo que esta haciendo es que el arrayList lo toma como nulo, pero solo es en el metodo getEmployee() donde obtengo la información, 
sin embargo si lo que hago es llenar el arrayList en el metodo getEmployee(), ahi si muestra la informacion en la tabla. ya probe de muchas formas y no se como hacer para que deje de limpiar el arrayList cuando intento desplegar la informacion, como puedo solucionar eso?
Gracias.

[[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLKvG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLKvG.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que la lista `array` contiene algún elemento antes de ejecutar el método `getEmployee()`?

Comment: Si contiene por que me permite loguear en la aplicación

Comment: Estoy seguro de `array` no llega con datos al método `getEmpleyee()`. Revisa el código de cada lugar donde manipules esa variable en busca de algo que pueda estar vacíandolo o cambiando su referencia.